# Standard deviation and alternate measures

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

Standard deviation is defined by $<(a - <a>)^2>$ for a continuous variable $a$.
Does the term $<|a - <a>|>$ contain the exactly the same information. Is there a one-to-one correspondence in their values. If not, is the latter a better measure of the "width" of the distribution compared to the former?

Comment: There should have many discussion about this topic in the web. See, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation#Mean_absolute_deviation_around_the_mean

Comment: @BGM Thanks for introducing me to the term - mean absolute deviation (MAD).

A quick search on this forum showed that the std. deviation weighs the larger (absolute) deviations more than the MAD. If someone knows of more intrinsic differences please do post them. Thanks.